Is there any method to convert a varchar with specific format into time in Oracle SQL?
I have a table with three columns, one of the columns  ateststatus_date has the following format: e.g:
28-MAY-24 11.57.20.000000 PM   

and it's defined as varchar(2). I used To_date() and To_timestamp() or even substring() to use it get the data for the month April 2024.
Unfortunately, none of the methods worked. I am so tired of struggling with this. Any solution for this type of formatting would be appreciated.
One of the methods I used:
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(lateststatus_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')  
      BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-APR-24 00:00:00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
          AND TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-24 23:59:59.999999', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF');


Your method seems correct (you could simply deal with the first 9 characters, and use TO_DATE, really). What are you observing? nothing gets selected? share some test data  here then.

You code works if the column is varchar2 and all of the values are formatted as shown, and actually has data in April (fiddle)); or even if it  is date or timestamp (as it should be) and NLS is set to get the output you showed (fiddle). Saying things don't work isn't helpful; if you get errors then show us what they are, and try to identify the data causing them. If you get no results show the data you expect to be included.

Your data is in May, not April, so will not be returned by your query.
If you use your query:
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP(lateststatus_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')  
       BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-APR-24 00:00:00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
           AND TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-24 23:59:59.999999', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF');

then for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (lateststatus_date) AS
SELECT '28-MAY-24 11.57.20.000000 PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01-APR-24 12.00.00.000000 AM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30-APR-24 11.59.59.999999 PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30-APR-24 11.59.59.999999999 PM' FROM DUAL;

The output (assuming that your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE is set to English or another appropriate language) is:



LATESTSTATUS_DATE




01-APR-24 12.00.00.000000 AM


30-APR-24 11.59.59.999999 PM



It does not return your row in May, because it is not in April; however it does return two rows that are in April (but not the third that is in April but is outside your range).

However, better would be to specify the language for the conversion (and you can use TIMESTAMP literals to eliminate the need to convert the lower- and upper-bounds from strings):
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP(
         lateststatus_date,
         'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       )  
       BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2024-04-01 00:00:00.000000000'
           AND TIMESTAMP '2024-04-30 23:59:59.999999999';

or using a inclusive lower-bound and an exclusive upper-bound to the range:
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP(
         lateststatus_date,
         'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) >= DATE '2024-04-01'
AND    TO_TIMESTAMP(
         lateststatus_date,
         'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) < DATE '2024-05-01'

Which both output:



LATESTSTATUS_DATE




01-APR-24 12.00.00.000000 AM


30-APR-24 11.59.59.999999 PM


30-APR-24 11.59.59.999999999 PM



fiddle

In my database, this is the default date format:
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
26.07.24

To make it more obvious, I'll change it to
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
26.07.2024 07:10:47

Value - that represents a date - in your case would then be
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '28-MAY-24 11.57.20.000000 PM' from dual)
  3  select to_date(substr(col, 1, 9), 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
28.05.2024 00:00:00

SQL>

This is a date datatype value. It defaults to midnight as you didn't say you need time component.

As of your query, it won't benefit from possible index on lateststatus_date (maybe you could/should create a function-based index, if performance is bad?) so you could put it as
select * 
from your_table
where to_char(to_date(substr(lateststatus_date, 1, 9), 
             'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english'), 'yyyymm') = '202404'

i.e. no need to use between as your example shows.

In Oracle, a DATE is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. It ALWAYS has those 7 components and is NEVER stored in any particular human-readable format. The default date format you mention is not the format of a date but is the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter that the database uses to implicitly convert strings to dates (and vice versa) and is used by some clients to display dates. [cont.]

The default NLS_DATE_FORMAT you mention is the default for CROATIA and RUSSIA (among others), the OP's format is the default NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT for AMERICA and  CHINA (among others) so arguing that the OP's query is wrong because the string-to-date conversion parameter does not match the default for your territory seems wrong (especially when it does match the default for two of the largest countries in the world with >20% of the world's population).
